# SQL convert failed to 1.23467e+006 EUR

Tags: sql, sql-server, currency

I've this value: 1.234.567,00 $ and i will update this in another table, with the following code:

```
UPDATE 
    TABLETWO
SET 
    USERDEFINED = CAST(CAST(INSERTED.NETAMOUNT AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + INSERTED.CURRENCY AS VARCHAR(128)),
FROM 
    INSERTED
WHERE 
    INSERTED.TABLEID = XDFDOCVECTOR.TABLEID
```

The output is 1.23467e+006 (in Webview) and in the Database 1234667 ?

The correct output must be: 1.234.567,00 (in webciew) and 1234567 in database

Comment: What are the values in `INSERTED.NETAMOUNT` and `INSERTED.CURRENCY` columns? Also what is the data type of `USERDEFINED `

Comment: please post some sample data.